# Find Bayesian estimator with random sample from poisson and prior distribution from exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator

Let $X_{1}$ .....$X_n$ be a random sample from Poisson distribution, prior distribution with parameter $\pi(\lambda) = \beta e^{-\beta\lambda}$. Find Bayesian estimator

I couldn't take integration joint density part, anyone has any clue? I really appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Show us what expression you couldn't integrate.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Comment: I have a hard time to use latex, can I write on paper and upload?

Comment: It's possible to do that, certainly, though the markup is better if you can manage.

Comment: I think I got it, it's Gamma Distribution (Sum(Xi)+1, n+beta)

Comment: Sounds like you could post an answer.

Comment: @Glen_b I remember there is website we can use math or latex, when you type, it shows up on the screen, but I forget which one. I used that before. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you enclose your mathematics between \$ signs it will (sometimes a bit slowly) render as you type here as well, at least it works for me. So if I type \$\$ and then put `\alpha` in between, if I scroll down a bit so I can see below the edit window I'd see an $\alpha$ on screen and it will continue to update, even as I am editing.